# JMeter extract 500 errors from list of URLs and output them in a csv file

Tags: regex, jmeter

I'm running JMeter 5.4 (via Jenkins) to work through a long list of URLs (from a .txt file) in order to check that they have a 200/301 Status Code.

When I run the test, some of them fail, so what I'd like to do is somehow extract any URLs that have a 500 status code, and then output these (just the 500 status code URLs) to a separate csv file so I can easily see what URLs fail.

I would also like to be able to view this (500 failure) new csv file in Jenkins (I have the performance module up and running), but think I'll try and walk before I run! :)

Is this possible, and if so how would I go about extracting 500 status code URLs in JMeter?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a JSR223Post processor to write the URLs to a CSV file.

1. Add a [JSR223_PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to your HTTP Request as a child element
2. Inside the script area check the response code (=='500') and write the URL

   ```
    println("Before checking the response code ")

    if (prev.getResponseCode().equalsIgnoreCase("500")) {
        //print 
        println("Start writing to file ")
        FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("failed-urls.csv",true);
        fstream.write(vars.get('URL')+"\n");
        fstream.close();
    }
   ```

[image]

Methods available from the [previous sample result](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getResponseCode--) (prev variable) can be found in API documentation.

JSR223 Post Processor need to be places as a child element to the HTTP Request

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info Janesh. In the 'Language' field of the JSR232 Post Processor, which did you select?Thanks

Comment: @DarrenHarley Please keep the Language field to default (groovy)

Comment: Ok, so I've copied the info from above @Janesh, but when I run the test locally it doesn't appear to create the new file (despite there being some 500 erroring URLs), and when I run the test via Jenkins, it fails with a Killed error in Jenkins. This same build passes without the new JSR223Post processor. Thanks

Comment: Do you see any error messages in the log ? e.g Permission issues etc?

Comment: No, there doesn't appear to be any error messages in the JMeter log. In my Results Tree (Listener), the 500 Status Code URLs are listed, but the expected new error logging file is not created.

Comment: @DarrenHarley Post processor need to be added as a child element to the HTTP Request. I have updated the code with print statements. Do you see the output in the console after executing the test ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) like Simple Data Writer in order to store the failed requests URLs into a file, example configuration for [Simple Data Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-save-response-data-in-jmeter):

[image]

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T, and apologies for the late reply. Although this does list the error-only in the defined file, what I have found is that (despite using the same config as above) the actual URL is not displayed when I search through the results in the Jenkins Performance plugin? Is this a separate issue with the Perfomance plugin , as it's the listing of the actual URLs that I need. Many thanks.